# Graphing natural logarithms

Tags: logarithms

I don't know how to obtain the graph of these functions. Could someone please help me? I know what the graph of ln looks like, but other then that I don't know where to go. Thank you for any help

$$\lim_{x\to -2^+}  \ln(x + 2)$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0}  \frac{x}{e^x-1}$$

Comment: The expressions you are writing down aren't functions; each expression is a number. What do you really mean to ask?

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to -2^+}\ln(x+2)=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\ln(x)=-\infty $$

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{e^x-1}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{\frac{e^x-e^0}{x-0}}=\frac{1}{\frac{de^x}{dx}\big|_{x=0}}=1$$

Comment: The first limit is incorrect. The OP is looking for the limit as $x\to-2^+$.

Comment: It's not clear (to me) what OP is looking for, @Gahawar, as OP asks for a graph but presents a limit.

Comment: @GerryMyerson You are correct; the OP's question is ambiguous. Perhaps he means that he wants to graph the respective function and then find the limit through such?

Comment: Sorry, let me clear up what i meant. Keeping the limit out of this, how would I graph the second expression. And Idm, your explanation was fantastic, but I (believe) that you are using L'hopitals rule, and I am required to figure this out some other way. Thank you for the help everyone!

Comment: Thanks. I'm absolutely not using l'Hopital rule. I juste apply the definition $$f'(a)=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$$

Comment: If your question is, how do you graph $x/(e^x-1)$, Student, then please edit the body of your question so that that's what it asks. People shouldn't have to read the comments on an answer to know what the question is!